# Is it possible to change domain/base URL of any website on internet

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome

I am a backend developer and develop APIs for my company.
Whenever I have to quickly test our website (admin panel) after changes in an API, I need a frontend developer who will replace the base URL to my ngrok (running on localhost).
It wastes the time of two people.
Is there any way I can change the domain in Chrome console?

**For example:**
Whenever the website sends a request to `live.com/users`.
I will replace `live.com` with my localhost before it sends the request.

Comment: I imagine a web extension may be able to do that - or a better development process

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can change the domain in Chrome console?

No.

---

The two obvious approaches to solving this problem are:

- Use a proxy server that can rewrite URLs (e.g. [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) lets you intercept requests for `http://example.com/api/` and forward them to `http://localhost:4321/`).
- Run a local instance of the frontend server which should have a way to easily configure the URL of the API server.